# Fredholm Index of Toeplitz operators with invertible and continuous symbol

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I'm working through the following proof in C* algebras by Murphy, and I'm stuck on a step in the proof. For reference, $\epsilon_n = z^n : T \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and $\Gamma = \text{span}(\epsilon_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$. Here is the current theorem I'm working through: [image]

Here is the theorem they are referencing:

[image]

I don't understand how they can conclude that $T_{e^{\psi''}}$ is invertible by the same argument for $T_{e^{\psi'}}$.  We know that $e^{\psi'} \in H^{\infty}$, so by theorem $3.5.6$, this operator is clearly invertible, but we only know that $e^{\overline{\psi}''} \in H^{\infty}$, not $e^{\psi''}$, so we can only conclude that $e^{\psi''} \in L^{\infty}(T)$, and so the commutivity property claimed by theorem $3.5.6$ doesn't hold.

What mistake am I making here?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you work with the conjugate function $\overline{\psi''}$
and deduce that $T_{e^{\overline{\psi''}}}$ is invertible.   Then you use that the adjoint of an invertible operator is
invertible, and that
$(T_f)^*=T_{\overline f}$.

Comment: Isn't $$(T_{e^{\overline{\psi''}}})^*=T_{\overline{e^{\overline{\psi''}}} = T_{e^{-\overline{\psi''}}} \neq T_{e^{\psi''}}$$?

Comment: There is no "$i$" in your exponential so conjugation doesn't call for a minus sign.

Comment: That was my problem, thank you!